# syntax error for javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, zooming, pan

While making an animation in javascript I had a problem to fix, but I don't see it. I'm trying to make the pan works with the "mover" function but I think I'm using wrongly the properties inside the "transformOrigin" or I'm missing some step, also it doesn't appear errors on the console.

```js
function cambio(c) {
  document.getElementById("pb").src=c;
}
function zoom() {
  document.getElementById("pb").style.transform="scale(1.8)";   
}
function zoomout() {
  document.getElementById("pb").style.transform="";
}
function mover(element) {
  document.getElementById("pb").style.transformOrigin=((event.pageX - element.offsetLeft) / element.width) * 100 + "% " + ((event.pageY - element.offsetTop) / element.height) * 100 + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
#big {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#pb{
  width: 300px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}
#tumbnail {
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tumbnail img{
  width: 60px
}
#tumbnail img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="tumbnail">
 <a href=""><img src="http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/1.jpg" onmouseover="cambio('http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/1.jpg')" ></a>
 <a href=""><img src="http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/2.jpg" onmouseover="cambio('http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/2.jpg')" ></a>
 <a href=""><img src="http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/3.jpg" onmouseover="cambio('http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/3.jpg')" ></a>
 <a href=""><img src="http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/4.jpg" onmouseover="cambio('http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/4.jpg')" ></a>
</div>
<div id="big">
 <img src="http://www.cosmoscreativeagency.com/imagenes/1.jpg" id="pb" onmouseover="zoom()" onmouseout="zoomout()" onmousemove="mover(this)">
</div>
```

Comment: What error does [your console report?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: offsetLeft is not defined
    at mover (http://localhost/kenny2/ejercicio2.html:55:71)
    at HTMLImageElement.onmousemove (http://localhost/kenny2/ejercicio2.html:41:93)

Comment: That's not a syntax error (it says "ReferenceError"). What are you trying to find the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of? Please read the off-topic reason above and edit the necessary information into your question.

Comment: no, I just don't know how to put those properties inside the transformOrigin, transformOrigin have two values, 'x' and 'y', this code is for the first axis: ((event.pageX - offsetLeft) / width) * 100 + '% ' ... the same for the next to it.

Comment: it says that offsetLeft is not defined cause it doesn't recognized it as a property but as I variable.... I need javascript recognize the property

Comment: please check the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `this` through.

So

```
function mover(element) {
  document.getElementById("pb").style.transformOrigin=((event.pageX - element.offsetLeft) / element.width) * 100 + "% " + ((event.pageY - element.offsetTop) / element.height) * 100 + "%";
}
```

And

```
... onmousemove="mover(this)" ...
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was easy, I was not seen it.